# Install Lazarus on Raspberry Pi

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, lazarus

I want to develop with Lazarus on Raspberry Pi, but until now I can't.

[Here](http://wiki.freepascal.org/Lazarus_on_Raspberry_Pi) I've read this:

*In the Raspbian OS it is easy to install Lazarus and Free Pascal. In order to do this simply open a terminal window and type: 


sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get upgrade

sudo apt-get install fpc

sudo apt-get install lazarus*

I've tryed to install FPC for Linux ARM, but the installer didn't work.
Moreover I dont't know where to get Lazarus for Linux ARM.

It seems that Lazarus and FPC for Linux are target to x86/x64 and not fot ARM.

Can someone help me where can I download one single bundled of binaries (Lazarus + FPC) that install out of the box (without the need of source compilation) in the same way as the Windows version?

Another question: is that possible to cross-compile from Windows to Raspbian? 
I've done cross-compilations many times but between other OSs.

Thank you

Comment: from this its clear u can get precompiled binaries  http://elinux.org/Lazarus_on_RPi ,so What the error u getting while installing just share the logs

Answer (score 1):

If you use the shell commands from above (those that begin with "sudo apt-get") you don't have to install anything in addition. Lazarus and FPC should be readily installed and available from the "Programming" section of the LXDE start menu.